# Sharepoint authentication. How to get SharePoint cookie from ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, adfs2.0

We code a Sharepoint-application, expand it as Provider-hosted, using the certificate, and anchor our MVC project to it
Expand all this on the same IIS the Sharepoint was expanded.

**Task #1:** a user logs in Sharepoint, launches our application; the application starts without any authorization request and gets the user from Sharepoint it logged in.

**Task #2:** If the Sharepoint service request is necessary, our application logs in Sharepoint under the same username the user logged in Sharepoint.

**We tried:**

**1)**  Building up Provider-hosted App, writing our MVC in it, creating a self-singing certificate, adjusting High-trusted between the Sharepoint site and our MVC.

**We got:** 
If our MVC uses Windows authentication, then when transferring to our application, the username and the password are requested over again; when entering them, we may get `ClientContext` through `TokenHelper` using the `GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity` method.

If Windows authentication is disabled, then the user is not logged in the Request, and this method responds Exception that the user is not logged in.

**2)**
We installed and adjusted ADFS, configured Sharepoint for work with ADFS, wrote addresses of Sharepoint and our application in Relaying Party Trusts (in `Identifiers and`WS-Federtation` Passive Endpoints)

**We got:**
A user logs in Sharepoint, and when transferring to our application, the latter gets the user data (Claims)

Thus, the first task has been discharged.
After that, a problem of gaining access to the Sharepoint services under the authorized user arose

We tried to get `AccessToken` for Sharepoint through the Claims we received
We tried to transfer the following Claims:

```
nii":"trusted:adfs
nii":"urn:office:idp:forms:adfs201 //adfs201 - name of our ADFS service
upn:UserLogin
emailaddress:UserEmail@domain.kz
```

After that, we called a method responding `AccessToken` as per the entered Claims

```
    string issuer = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceRealm) ? issuerApplication : string.Format("{0}@{1}", issuerApplication, sourceRealm);
    string nameid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceRealm) ? sourceApplication : string.Format("{0}@{1}", sourceApplication, sourceRealm);
    string audience = string.Format("{0}/{1}@{2}", targetApplication, targetApplicationHostName, targetRealm);

    List<JsonWebTokenClaim> actorClaims = new List<JsonWebTokenClaim>();
    actorClaims.Add(new JsonWebTokenClaim(JsonWebTokenConstants.ReservedClaims.NameIdentifier, nameid));
    if (trustedForDelegation && !appOnly)
    {
        actorClaims.Add(new JsonWebTokenClaim(TokenHelper.TrustedForImpersonationClaimType, "true"));
    }       

    if (addSamlClaim)
        actorClaims.Add(new JsonWebTokenClaim(samlClaimType, samlClaimValue));

    // Create token
    JsonWebSecurityToken actorToken = new JsonWebSecurityToken(
        issuer: issuer,
        audience: audience,
        validFrom: DateTime.UtcNow,
        validTo: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(TokenLifetimeMinutes),
        signingCredentials: SigningCredentials,
        claims: actorClaims);

    string actorTokenString = new JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler().WriteTokenAsString(actorToken);

    if (appOnly)
    {
        // App-only token is the same as actor token for delegated case
        return actorTokenString;
    }

    List<JsonWebTokenClaim> outerClaims = null == claims ? new List<JsonWebTokenClaim>() : new List<JsonWebTokenClaim>(claims);
    outerClaims.Add(new JsonWebTokenClaim(ActorTokenClaimType, actorTokenString));

    //****************************************************************************
    //SPSAML
    if (addSamlClaim)
        outerClaims.Add(new JsonWebTokenClaim(samlClaimType, samlClaimValue));
    //****************************************************************************

    JsonWebSecurityToken jsonToken = new JsonWebSecurityToken(
        nameid, // outer token issuer should match actor token nameid
        audience,
        DateTime.UtcNow,
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        outerClaims);

    string accessToken = new JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler().WriteTokenAsString(jsonToken);
```

Then, we tried to get `ClientContext`, using the method:

```
GetClientContextWithAccessToken(targetApplicationUri.ToString(), accessToken);
```

But we got an error report:

```
401 Unauthorized
```

`ClientID` and `IssureID` were written right, lowercase

After that, we decided to request `SecurityToken` from ADFS with the help of `username` and `password`. Having received it, we requested authorization in SharepointSTS using `SecurityToken`. Then, our application got Cookie Sharepoint, which were anchored to the query (added in `CookieContainer FedAuth`) to the Sharepoint services. When activating `ExecutingWebRequest += ClientContext_ExecutingWebRequest`, the above-mentioned happens.

**But** for this, one should use the `username` and the `password` to be requested once again.

In case we do not submit the `username` and the `password`, then ADFS responds with `SecurityToken` with the data of user, under the name of which the applications pool was started. And we need `SecurityToken` of the **user logged in SharePoint**.
We also tried to emit `SecurityToken`

```
var session = System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(ClientPrincipals, "context", DateTime.UtcNow, System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), true);
System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(session, true);
```

But the response was not the same we needed for SharePoint authorization.

In ADFS in Endpoints, we adjust URL; that very `SecurityToken (wresult)` we need for SharePoint authorization is sent to it by POST query. The problem is that we cannot receive this query in the application as it is broadcasted in status 302 and redirected to our application by the GET method, without `SecurityToken` with our Cookie.

**The question is:** how can we get `SecurityToken` of the user logged in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Going on a whim here, but it sounds like you need to create a Claims Provider, which is a class that Inherits from SPClaimProvider.

The people picker in sharepoint, which is the control you use to select people and groups get's all of it's people and groups from Claim Providers.

Out of the box, the following Claim Providers exist,

AllUsersClaimProvider
FormsClaimsProvider
ActiveDirectoryClaimsProvider

If you need additional claims resolution, you have to write one, which isn't so bad.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537299(v=office.15).aspx

Basically, FillClaimsForEntity is where you can issue new claims to an Identity Principal.

The two Resolve Overloads is where you see if there is a Claim match for the input.

E.g. say you type in "Bob" in the people picker.  The people picker then uses the SPClaimsOperationManager* (forget exact spelling), to call Resolve(string input...) on every claim provider registered in the farm.

So say we are talking about the Forms Claims Provider.  It would check to see if there is a user with a username or email address matching Bob.  For each user mapping bob it will create a picker entity and set it's claim type to FormsLogonUser with a value of bob etc.  And it adds each one to the result.

So when it's done, you will either see Bob in the People Picker as having been selected, or you will see Bob with a red underline meaning their were multiple matches and you need to pick on.

It sounds to me like you need to build one to enable the people picker to work with your new claims.

Once you have a claim provider made and registered, you can use the people picker to grant access to the site using your claims.

For an example scenario, I once made a claim provider that issued claims based on what products users had purchased.

So I made a claim type of "http://blah.com/schema/claims/product" (this can be any unique string you want it to be) And the values were things like "pd.1234.0". Now in FillClaimsForEntities I looked up the user on entity parameter in our database to get all of their products.  Then I created a product claim for each product and added them to the claims list.

Then in Resolve I would look to see if a product existed with an ID or Display Name mathing the resolve input and create a picker entity if it did.

Same thing in Search.

Then I went into our product pages and granted access to the page to anyone having that product's claim using the people picker. "works like picking roles in forms authentication" kind of.

Also you can code support for Claims Heirarchy and you can have multiple trees in the people picker, 1 tree for each claim type you are working with.

E.g. say "Bob" brings back a person, a book, and a manager.  You could have 3 heirarchies, 1 for people, 1 for books, 1 for managers, etc.  And make the claims of that type show up in that tree.

I took it a step farther and made an Access Denied Handler so that if a User got access denied for not being in that product claimed, it redirected them to that products purchasing page.